# Issue with SSH Keys

Tags: linux, ssh, centos7, redhat, ssh-keys

I'm having something very similar to: [SSHD Gives error could not open Authorized Keys, although permissions seem correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688844/sshd-gives-error-could-not-open-authorized-keys-although-permissions-seem-corre)
but not exactly the same thing.

When I try to connect to server with my user account I see the following error message in `/var/log/secure`
The error message says:

```
Could not open authorized keys '/home/<username>/$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory
```

which makes perfect sense, but when I go to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` folder to see where the `sshd` service should look for my authorized key folder it shows `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` so i'm not sure why SSH is trying to append my `/home/<username>` to `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`. I did double check and ran the following cmd: `echo $HOME` just to make sure `$HOME` wasn't set improperly. If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think $HOME is understood in that file? It's parsed by the sshd daemon, not the shell. It looks like maybe %h is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sshd_config` is not a shell script. `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` is taken as a literal path, and since it does not start with `/`, it is appended to the user's home directory.

You should replace `$HOME` with the token that `sshd` interprets as the user's home directory, or simply use the relative path `.ssh/authorized_keys` (which, by the way, is the default).

```
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```